validate and convert input string in react
I have one form in react in which I have used formik and Yup library for validations. I have requirement that input field should allow only lowercase alphanumeric values which allow hyphen and length between 2 to 30 characters. Also if user is typing Uppercase letters or space then convert that string to lowercase and replace space with hyphen.
e.g. for input like "Shop name123" should convert to "shop-name123"
formik validation is as follows:
postfix: Yup.string()
  .required(message.ENTER_POSTFIX)
  .matches(new RegExp("^[a-z0-9- ]{2,30}$"), {
    message: message.PUBLIC_URL_POSTFIX_INVALID,
  })

on change of that field I have following code
<Field
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  style={{ marginTop: "32px" }}
  value={values.postfix? values.postfix: ""}
  name="postfix"
  onChange={(e) => {
    setFieldValue(
      "postfix",
      tranformStrToVar(e.target.value)
    );
  }}
/>

method tranformStrToVar as follows
export function tranformStrToVar(str) {
  let newStr = "";
  if (str) {
    newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
  }
  return newStr;
}

With above code working for some cases and getting failed if input has only "-----" etc. That also should not allowed.
How should I validate and convert input at same time and get valid, required input having lowercase alphanumeric seperated by hyphen having character length between 2 to 30 ?
What should I do to get valid and expected output?
Please help and guide. Thanks
EDIT
Invalid inputs are as follows (other than lowercase alphanumeric seperated by hyphen having character length between 2 to 30 )
---- (only hyphens not allowed)
-------test-test-test------- (should convert to test-test-test)
----test (should convert to test)
test---- (should convert to test)

Shouldn't your match regex at least indicate then that it should start with any lowercase or number (eagerly, and potentially have a hyphen or space)? Then you would need to replace the hyphens from the start and end of the string during the transformation?

So as a suggestion, your regex match could be ^(([a-z0-9]{1,}-{0,})?){2,30}. This would exclude spaces from the match, and hyphens from the start. Then as mentioned before, just handle the transformation better, by removing the hyphens at the start of a string and at the end of a string

You may use the following approach of the codebase to replace characters on keystroke.
But for the final validation while submitting the form, you need this regex:
regex = /^(?=.*[a-z0-9])[a-z0-9-]{2,30}$/gm;
here (?=.*[a-z0-9]) it ensures that the string at least has alphanumeric.
I think you can adopt this into react as I did this on jquery.


const hyphenCheckRegex = /^\-+|\-+$/gm;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myInput').on('keypress', function(event) {
          setTimeout(() => {
        let inputVal = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
       // let char = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();

        event.preventDefault();
        let outputVal=tranformStrToVar(inputVal);
        $(this).val(outputVal);
     }, 0);
    });
});

    $('#myInput').on('blur', function() {
        let inputVal = $(this).val();
        
        // Regular expression to match only leading or trailing hyphens
        const hyphenCheckRegex = /^-+|-+$/g;
        
        // Remove the leading or trailing hyphens
        let cleanedInput = inputVal.replace(hyphenCheckRegex, '');
        
        // Update the input field with the cleaned value
        $(this).val(cleanedInput);
    });

function tranformStrToVar(str) {
  let newStr = "";
  if (str) {
   newStr = str.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
  }
  return newStr;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Type something...">



